# Ajaxify or pjax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pjax, ajaxify

What are the main differences here? Ajaxify seems much more lightweight then pjax. I know it is a very common plugin on wordpress, but find it hard to find any good documentation on implementing to normal websites.

Pjax, seems to be very heavy but does the same thing as Ajaxify?

I basically want to have transitional fade out/in effect when navigating through pages on websites and to utilise history.js for SEO and navigation purposes. Can someone explain to me the major differences with these two and what will be best to use?

Ajaxify: https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify

Pjax: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Comment: There are already a few Stack Overflow questions that discuss fade-in/fade out page transitions. I hope this search query will help you: https://www.google.com/#q=fade+in+fade+out+page+transition